# Calculate distance between coordinates inside Firebase query

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, location

I'm trying to do the following search + calculation in my app:

1. find in the database who has an item
2. if someone has the item - > find in the database his location
3. calculate the distance between me to the user who has this item.

I'm doing the following query:

```
private void WhoHasItemAroundMe(Object Lat, Object Lon, int Radius){
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("Items").whereEqualTo("ItemID", itemID).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LocationsActivity.this, "ID" +document.getData().get( "UserID" ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        db.collection("Users").document(document.getData().get( "UserID" ).toString()).collection( "Location" ).get()
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(LocationsActivity.this, "LAT" +document.getData().get( "Lat" ) + "LON" + document.getData().get( "Lon" ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                GoalLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(document.getData().get( "Lat" ).toString()));
                                                GoalLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(document.getData().get( "Lon" ).toString()));
                                                MyLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf( Lat.toString()));
                                                MyLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf( Lon.toString()));



                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            Log.d("ERROR", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
}
```

However, for some reason I keep getting the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.Location.setLatitude(double)' on a null object reference

Thing is that when I used `Toast(Lat)` I do get the result so I can't understand why it says it is null.

Comment: It looks like `GoalLocation` or `MyLocation` is `null`. Make sure that you initialize them before you use them

Comment: Ye...sometimes it also happens XD, thank you